# Toggle single element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle

I have one question. I created contact form  in react and I want to collapsed only single contact, which was clicked. Toggle is method which should collapse it. And colapse is state. My problem is that when I click it affect all contact and all are collapsed. How can I improve it?

ContactBook.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Contact from "../Contact/Contact";
import "./ContactBook.css";

class ContactBook extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
          colapse :true,
          contacts: [
              {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Propulsion Academy',
                address: 'Zurich',
                avatar: 'propulsion-academy-logo.png'
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Propulsion Academy',
                address: 'Luzern',
                avatar: 'propulsion-academy-logo.png'
              },  
              {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Propulsion Academy',
                address: 'Munich',
                avatar: 'propulsion-academy-logo.png'
              },                
            ],
          };     
      }  

      toggle=()=>{
        const doesShow = this.state.colapse;
        this.setState({colapse: !doesShow});
      }

      deleteContact=(contactIndex)=>{
        //with slice method we create copy of an array
        const contacts =this.state.contacts.slice();
        contacts.splice(contactIndex, 1);
        this.setState({contacts: contacts})
      }

      //get name from input
      addName = e =>{
        this.setState({ 
        name: e.target.value,  
        })
      }
      //get address from input
      addAddress = e =>{
        this.setState({ 
        address: e.target.value,
        })
      }

      //update state on button click
      handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()  
        if(this.state.name && this.state.address) {
          this.setState(state =>{
            const newContact = {
              id: Math.max(...state.contacts.map(c => c.id))+1,
              name: this.state.name,
              address: this.state.address,
            }
            return{
              contacts:[...state.contacts, newContact]
              }
          })   
        }
      }
    

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="contactBook">
            
             <form className ="addContact"  >
            <p>New Contact</p>
            <label id="name"><p>Name</p><input type='text' id="name" onChange={this.addName}/></label> 
            <label id="address"><p>Address:</p><input type='text' id="address" onChange={this.addAddress} /></label> 
            <input type='file' name='file'  />
            <button type='submit' onClick= {this.handleSubmit}>SUBMIT</button>
          </form>
            
            
            <div className="contacts">         
            {this.state.contacts.map((contact, index) =>
              < Contact key={contact.id} contact={contact} delete={()=>this.deleteContact(index)} colapse={this.state.colapse} toggle={this.toggle}/>)              
            }
              </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
};

export default ContactBook;
```

Contact.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Contact.css";
import avatar from '../assets/user.png'




const Contact = (props) =>{
       
    return (
            <div className = "col" >
                <img src={avatar}  alt="avatar" onClick={props.toggle}/>           
                {props.colapse === true ?
                <div>
                    <p>Name: {props.contact.name}</p> 
                    <p>Address: {props.contact.address}</p>
                    <button onClick={props.delete}> Delete </button>   
                 </div> : null
                  }

            </div>
        )
};

export default Contact;
```

Comment: Move the collapse state into the `Contact` component and deal with it there. That also makes it better for re-renders

Comment: @Michaela even my answer is also working!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to you to move the collapse and his method to the Contact component it self like this :

```
const Contact = (props) =>{
    [collapse,setCollapse] = useState(true)
    return (
            <div className = "col" >
                <img src={avatar}  alt="avatar" onClick{()=>setCollape(prev=>!prev)}/>           
                {collapse === true ?
                <div>
                    <p>Name: {props.contact.name}</p> 
                    <p>Address: {props.contact.address}</p>
                    <button onClick={props.delete}> Delete </button>   
                 </div> : null
                  }

            </div>
        )
};
```

In this component I created a state that will manage the collapse for each of the component the render in the map.
further more, the prev give you the last value you submit  and it's best practice to use the prev instead of just `setCollapse(!collapse)`

Answer (score 1):

You have one function for all contacts, and since you use .map() they will all behave the same, since toggling one toggles the state which is used to render all individual contacts. The solution would be to pass the selected contact in your state so your app actually knows which one is to be rendered! Hopefully that makes sense!

Good luck and let us know how things work out!

Comment: well it's better to pass the collapse to the Contact Component to handle with if there is no use in the form itself beacuse like this you don't need another state

Comment: Actually you can just use this one state and render what you want based off this one state, passing the setSelectedContact function as a prop to the <Contact/> component. I agree the less states the better, but here this would be the same thing. Instead of writing the toggle function in the <Contact/>,you write it in the <ContactBook/> and you're good to go! Plus you could use a hook with "useState" which would make things even easier

Comment: The key here is to not render based on a click, but rather set the selected item based on a click, with a function that renders only a selected item or none if none was chosen.

Comment: I dont know so much beucase collpase his still you want to manage what collapse and what not sometimes in the future you may want two that will show up in the same time

Comment: That's the thing, two things will never render at the same time if you use this approach, since you can only set one element in your state. Also, why are your contacts hardcoded in your state? You'd be better off letting them live in a separate object, giving you more flexibility and not cluttering your state like so

Comment: Anyway, your project, your rules :) That's my two cents about it!

Comment: so in this senrio you are right if you want only one

Answer (score 0):

This is it:
ContactBook.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Contact from "./Contact";
// import "./ContactBook.css";

class ContactBook extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      contacts: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Propulsion Academy",
          address: "Zurich",
          avatar: "propulsion-academy-logo.png",
          colapse: true
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Propulsion Academy",
          address: "Luzern",
          avatar: "propulsion-academy-logo.png",
          colapse: true
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Propulsion Academy",
          address: "Munich",
          avatar: "propulsion-academy-logo.png",
          colapse: true
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  // toggle = () => {
  //   const doesShow = this.state.colapse;
  //   this.setState({ colapse: !doesShow });
  // };

  deleteContact = contactIndex => {
    //with slice method we create copy of an array
    const contacts = this.state.contacts.slice();
    contacts.splice(contactIndex, 1);
    this.setState({ contacts: contacts });
  };
  togglecontact = contactIndex => {
    let contacts = this.state.contacts.slice();
    contacts[contactIndex].colapse = !contacts[contactIndex].colapse;
    this.setState({ contacts: contacts });
  };

  //get name from input
  addName = e => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    });
  };
  //get address from input
  addAddress = e => {
    this.setState({
      address: e.target.value
    });
  };

  //update state on button click
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.name && this.state.address) {
      this.setState(state => {
        const newContact = {
          id: Math.max(...state.contacts.map(c => c.id)) + 1,
          name: this.state.name,
          address: this.state.address
        };
        return {
          contacts: [...state.contacts, newContact]
        };
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="contactBook">
        <form className="addContact">
          <p>New Contact</p>
          <label id="name">
            <p>Name</p>
            <input type="text" id="name" onChange={this.addName} />
          </label>
          <label id="address">
            <p>Address:</p>
            <input type="text" id="address" onChange={this.addAddress} />
          </label>
          <input type="file" name="file" />
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
            SUBMIT
          </button>
        </form>

        <div className="contacts">
          {this.state.contacts.map((contact, index) => (
            <Contact
              key={contact.id}
              contact={contact}
              togglecontact={() => this.togglecontact(index)}
              delete={() => this.deleteContact(index)}
              colapse={this.state.colapse}
              toggle={this.toggle}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ContactBook;
```

contactbook.js

```
import React from "react";
// import "./Contact.css";

const Contact = props => {
  let buffer;
  props.contact.colapse === true
    ? (buffer = (
        <div>
          <p>Name: {props.contact.name}</p>
          <p>Address: {props.contact.address}</p>
          <button onClick={props.delete}> Delete </button>
        </div>
      ))
    : null;

  return (
    <div className="col">
      <img
        onClick={props.togglecontact}
        src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
      />
      {buffer}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

can check it at:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mrvrr1?file=src%2FContact.js

only Toggling single element.